# Loop through columns with conditional if in Excel

Tags: vba

I'm needing to write an excel script to fill in some data.  Essentially what needs to happen is the script should loop through each record and when it hits a "1" it should follow each cell with another "1" until it hits the next "1".  My goal is to fill in the gaps between 1s with more 1s.

Here's what I have so far:

```
Dim i, j As Integer

finalrow = Cells(665, 1).End(x1up).Row
finalcol = Cells(1, 10).End(x1toleft).Column

For i = 1 To finalrow
    If Cells(i, j).Value = "0" Then
        For j = 1 To finalcol
            Next j
    Else
        For j = 1 To finalcol
            Next j
            Cells(i, j).Value = "1"
    End If
Next i
```

I keep getting an error when this is ran.

My data is structured like this:

```
0   0   1   0   0   0   1   0   0   0
1   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0
0   0   0   1   0   0   1   0   0   0
0   0   0   1   1   0   0   0   0   0
```

Any help or advise is much appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few issues with your code (particularly that FOR LOOP doesn't make much sense).

I took what you had and made comments and changed to quasi-fit what you are asking for.

Absorb:

```
Option Explicit 'USE THIS!!!

Sub Test()

    'Dim i, j As Integer NO! "i" is Varaint and you want integer
    Dim i As Integer, j As Integer 'Use this syntax for single line declaration 
    'Adding "Option Explicit" makes you declare these two variables
    Dim finalRow As Integer
    Dim finalCol As Integer

    Dim oneFound As Boolean 'This will be used on the for loop


    finalRow = Range("A65536").End(xlUp).Row 'Do this.  I'm not sure your code works:  Cells(665, 1).End(xlUp).Row 'you had x1, not "XL" (typo)
    finalCol = Range("IV1").End(xlToLeft).Column ''Do this.  I'm not sure your code works:  Cells(1, 10).End(xlToLeft).Column 'had x1, not "XL" (typo)

    oneFound = False
    For i = 1 To finalRow 'You're looping through rows here, now you need to loop through columns

        'REASON FOR YOUR ERROR:  Variable j below is zero at this point and there is no cell (1,0).
        'If Cells(i, j).Value = "0" Then
        For j = 1 To finalCol
            If Cells(i, j).Value = 1 And Not oneFound Then 'We found a one in a cell and we haven't started in filling ones yet
                oneFound = True
            ElseIf Cells(i, j).Value <> 1 And oneFound Then 'You found a one previously in the row and you want to start filling in data
                Cells(i, j).Value = 1
            ElseIf Cells(i, j).Value = 1 And oneFound Then 'You found a one previously in the row and you just found your next one
                'Don't know what you want to do here
                'Setting oneFound to false in case you want to stop filling in data
                oneFound = False
            Else
              'All scenarioes should be covered for what you asking above.
              'You could do something else here should you find the need
            End If
        Next j

        oneFound = False 'Reinitialize for next row
    Next i


End Sub
```

Comment: +1 for a helpful explanation!

Comment: @ray023, I would suggest you use `Range("A" & ActiveSheet.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row` to get the last row as after Excel 2007 there can be more than 65536 rows

Answer (score 0):

If all you are trying to do is replace zeros with ones, instead of looping through the data you could use search and replace functionality.

```
Cells.Select
Selection.Replace What:="0", Replacement:="1"
```

Comment: That's essentially what I need, however it's conditional.  I need to replace the zeros that are between the ones rather than all the zeros.  So the first line would end up looking like:  0   0   1   1   1   1   1   0   0   0

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub abc()

j = 2
ActiveSheet.Range("a1").Select
ActiveSheet.Range("a65536").Select
lastrow = Selection.End(xlUp).Row

'/// column a
ActiveSheet.Range("a3:a" & lastrow).Select

    Selection.AutoFilter
    ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$A$" & lastrow).AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="="

    Application.CutCopyMode = False

    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight)).Select
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("Sheet2").Select
    lrow = ActiveSheet.Range("A65536").End(xlUp).Row
    ActiveSheet.Range("a" & lrow).Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Sheets("Sheet1").Select
    Selection.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.EntireRow.Delete
 Selection.AutoFilter

'column b///////////
ActiveSheet.Range("b3:b" & lastrow).Select

    Selection.AutoFilter
    ActiveSheet.Range("$b$1:$b$" & lastrow).AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="="

    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight)).Select
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("Sheet2").Select
    lrow = activehseet.Range("A65536").End(xlUp).Row
    ActiveSheet.Range("a" & lrow).Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Sheets("Sheet1").Select
    Selection.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.EntireRow.Delete
     Selection.AutoFilter

    'column c////////////

 ActiveSheet.Range("c3:c" & lastrow).Select

    Selection.AutoFilter
    ActiveSheet.Range("$c$1:$c$" & lastrow).AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="SG Plus", _
    Operator:=xlOr, Criteria2:="=Select"
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight)).Select
'    Selection.Copy
'    Sheets("Sheet2").Select
'    lrow = activehseet.Range("A65536").End(xlUp).Row
'    ActiveSheet.Range("a" & lrow).Select
'    ActiveSheet.Paste
'    Sheets("Sheet1").Select
    Selection.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.EntireRow.Delete
    Selection.AutoFilter


'column c again/////////////
ActiveSheet.Range("c3:c" & lastrow).Select

    Selection.AutoFilter
    ActiveSheet.Range("$c$1:$c$" & lastrow).AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="="

    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight)).Select
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("Sheet2").Select
    lrow = activehseet.Range("A65536").End(xlUp).Row
    ActiveSheet.Range("a" & lrow).Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Sheets("Sheet1").Select
    Selection.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.EntireRow.Delete
     Selection.AutoFilter

'//////////////////////////// changes oct 21 end


ActiveSheet.Range("a1").Select
For i = 3 To lastrow
Range("a" & i).Select
If Range("a" & i).Value = "MidAmerica" Or Range("a" & i).Value = "Northeast" Or Range("a" & i).Value = "Southeast" Or _
Range("a" & i).Value = "West" Then
GoTo cont
Else

Rows(i).Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Selection.Cut
    Sheets("Sheet2").Select
    Range("a" & j).Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    j = j + 1
    Sheets("sheet1").Select
       Selection.Delete Shift:=xlUp
   End If
cont:
Next i


'/////// column b ///////////

ActiveSheet.Range("a1").Select
For i = 3 To lastrow
Range("b" & i).Select
If Range("b" & i).Value = "CA" Or Range("b" & i).Value = "AZ" Then
GoTo cont2
Else

Rows(i).Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Selection.Cut
    Sheets("Sheet2").Select
    Range("a" & j).Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    j = j + 1
    Sheets("sheet1").Select
    Selection.Delete Shift:=xlUp
   End If
cont2:
Next i

'///////////column c //////////

ActiveSheet.Range("a1").Select
For i = 3 To lastrow
Range("c" & i).Select
If Range("c" & i).Value = "SG" Then
GoTo cont3
Else

Rows(i).Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Selection.Cut
    Sheets("Sheet2").Select
    Range("a" & j).Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    j = j + 1
    Sheets("sheet1").Select
    Selection.Delete Shift:=xlUp
   End If
cont3:
Next i

'//////////column l/////////////
ActiveSheet.Range("a1").Select
For i = 3 To lastrow
Range("l" & i).Select
If Range("l" & i).Value >= "01/01/2014" And Range("l" & i).Value <= "30/06/2014" Then
GoTo cont4
Else

Rows(i).Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Selection.Cut
    Sheets("Sheet2").Select
    Range("a" & j).Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    j = j + 1
    Sheets("sheet1").Select
    Selection.Delete Shift:=xlUp
   End If
cont4:
Next i

'//////////column m/////////////
ActiveSheet.Range("a1").Select
For i = 3 To lastrow
Range("m" & i).Select
If Range("m" & i).Value >= "12/01" Or Range("m" & i).Value <= "12/05" Then
GoTo cont5
Else

Rows(i).Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Selection.Cut
    Sheets("Sheet2").Select
    Range("a" & j).Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    j = j + 1
    Sheets("sheet1").Select
    Selection.Delete Shift:=xlUp
   End If
cont5:
Next i

'//////////column q and r/////////////
ActiveSheet.Range("a1").Select
For i = 3 To lastrow
Range("q" & i).Select
If Range("q" & i).Value <> " " And Range("r" & i).Value <> " " And Range("u" & i).Value <> " " _
And Range("z" & i).Value <> " " And Range("aa" & i).Value <> " " And Range("ab" & i).Value <> " " _
And Range("b" & i).Value <> " " And Range("j" & i).Value <> " " Then
GoTo cont6
Else

Rows(i).Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Selection.Cut
    Sheets("Sheet2").Select
    Range("a" & j).Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    j = j + 1
    Sheets("sheet1").Select
    Selection.Delete Shift:=xlUp
   End If
cont6:
Next i


End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

you could do that with the use of a formula and replace the existing values like this:

```
Sub Test2()

Dim iRow As Integer
Dim iDx As Integer
Dim iLastRow As Integer
Dim sConcatValues As String
Dim sFormula As String

    sConcatValues = "A:A&B:B&C:C&D:D&E:E&F:F&G:G&H:H&I:I&J:J"

    sFormula = "=LEFT(" & sConcatValues & ",FIND(""1""," _
                        & sConcatValues & ")) & REPT(""1"",FIND(""1""," _
                        & sConcatValues & ",FIND(""1""," _
                        & sConcatValues & ")+1)-1-FIND(""1""," _
                        & sConcatValues & ")) & MID(" _
                        & sConcatValues & ",FIND(""1""," _
                        & sConcatValues & ",FIND(""1""," _
                        & sConcatValues & ")+1),LEN(" _
                        & sConcatValues & "))"

    iLastRow = Range("A" & ActiveSheet.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

    iRow = 1

    ' put in the formula to fix the values
    Range("L1:L" & iLastRow).Formula = sFormula
    Range("L1:L" & iLastRow).Copy
    Range("L1:L" & iLastRow).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

    ' now copy over the new values, and clean up!
    For iRow = 1 To iLastRow
        For iDx = 1 To Len(Range("L" & iRow).Text)
            Cells(iRow, iDx) = Mid(Range("L" & iRow).Text, iDx, 1)
        Next
    Next

    Range("L1:L" & iLastRow).Clear
    'Range("A1").Activate

End Sub
```

this is the formula that is used:

```
=LEFT(A:A&B:B&C:C&D:D&E:E&F:F&G:G&H:H&I:I&J:J,FIND("1",A:A&B:B&C:C&D:D&E:E&F:F&G:G&H:H&I:I&J:J)) & REPT("1",FIND("1",A:A&B:B&C:C&D:D&E:E&F:F&G:G&H:H&I:I&J:J,FIND("1",A:A&B:B&C:C&D:D&E:E&F:F&G:G&H:H&I:I&J:J)+1)-1-FIND("1",A:A&B:B&C:C&D:D&E:E&F:F&G:G&H:H&I:I&J:J)) & MID(A:A&B:B&C:C&D:D&E:E&F:F&G:G&H:H&I:I&J:J,FIND("1",A:A&B:B&C:C&D:D&E:E&F:F&G:G&H:H&I:I&J:J,FIND("1",A:A&B:B&C:C&D:D&E:E&F:F&G:G&H:H&I:I&J:J)+1),LEN(A:A&B:B&C:C&D:D&E:E&F:F&G:G&H:H&I:I&J:J))
```

basically you concatenate the cells, then do a find for the first `1`, followed by the next `1`, and fill in between using the `REPT` function

Philip

Answer (score 0):

Including this might help as well.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa213567%28v=office.11%29.aspx

```
Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell)
```

Instead of using

```
finalRow = Range("A65536")...
finalCol = Range("IV1").End(xlToLeft).Column
```